# how to stop a firebase counter at 0

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

ive been using this counting method in firebase that counts up likes.

```
  ref.child("downloads").runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
            if (mutableData.getValue() != null) {
                int value = mutableData.getValue(Integer.class);
                if (increment) {
                    value++;
                } else {
                    value--;
                }
                mutableData.setValue(value);
            }
            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }
```

i have a variable in my database called downloads which is automatically set to 0 when user signs up. then when a user clicks a button they get rewarded 5 downloads for watching a short reward advert.. how can i edit this code to instead of counting up it counts down from 5 - 0 then stops?

Comment: `if (value > 0)`?

Comment: Have you tried Frank's suggestion? Besides that, please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Thanks guys will try this later n get back to you.  If it doesn't work I'll edit my question to add JSON :)

Comment: just thought id let you know that works brilliantly thanks :)